# Induction: $2^n = \sum_{v=0}^{n} \binom{n}{v}$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, induction

I have to prove the following identity for $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$\displaystyle 2^n = \sum_{v=0}^{n} \binom{n}{v}$

Is there a way to show it through induction? Or is there a easier way? My steps so far:

$\displaystyle n=2: 2^2=\sum_{v=0}^{2} \binom{n}{v} \Rightarrow 2 \cdot 2 = \binom{0}{2} + \binom{1}{2} + \binom{2}{2} \Rightarrow 4 = 1 + 2 +1 \checkmark$

Now we suppose that the idenity is true for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then it has to be true for $n+1 \in \mathbb{N}$, too:

$\displaystyle n \to n+1: 2^{n+1} = \sum_{v=0}^{n+1} \binom{n}{v} \Rightarrow 2^n \cdot 2 = \sum_{v=0}^{n} \binom{n}{v}+\binom{n+1}{v} \Rightarrow \ldots ?$

Comment: Easiest way is to consider the binomial expansion of $(1+1)^n$, if you can take that to be given.

Comment: you can also show it using induction. just try to find a pattern between two consecutive binomial coefficients, its easy ;)

Comment: The deleted answer gave what I consider the easiest argument: $\binom{n}v$ is the number of subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ of cardinality $v$; taking the sum over $v=0,\ldots,n$ gives the total number of subsets, which of course is $2^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Newton's binomial that states that $(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^{k}b^{n-k}$. Thus you have that $2^n=(1+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}1^{k}1^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}$

Comment: Wow, so simple and elegant at the same time. Thank you for sharing this!

Answer (score 0):

$2^{n+1}=2^n.2=2.\sum_{v=0}^{n} \binom{n}{v}= \binom{n}{0}+\big\{\binom{n}{0}+ \binom{n}{1}\big\} +\big\{ \binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}\big\}+\dots + \binom{n}{n}+ \binom{n}{n}$

It would be necessary to use :$$\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r-1}=\binom{n+1}{r}$$